# How do I fix CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I started learning about discord.js, but now I am facing this issue.
I tried some googling, but I couldn't manage to fix it.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
// const Discord = require('discord.js');

// Using Intents class
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('message', (msg) => {
  // Send back a reply when the specific command has been written by a user.
  if (msg.content === '!hello') {
    msg.reply('Hello, World!');
  }
});

client.login('my_token');
```

This is the error I am getting:

[image]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to specify the events which you want your bot to receive using [gateway intents](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html).

Instead of

```
const client = new Discord.Client();
```

Use

```
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [Enter intents here] })
```

For example

***Discord.js v14:***

```
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [
  Discord.GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
  Discord.GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages
]})
```

***Discord.js v13:***

`const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] })`

---

> Here's another useful page: *[Gateways](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway)*

---

- Intents help you control which events your bot receives. See [Privileged Intents](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#privileged-intents) for more information.
- You need node.js 16.6 or higher to use discord.js13. `npm install node@16` in shell.
- The list of client events are under the events tab at [Client](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client).

Comment: Yeah, actually we should focus on the versions of some  dependencies, like discord.js, the npm you use now  and so on. And the syntax must match the version

Answer (score 4):

You can instead just degrade the discord.js version by typing this into the shell:

```
npm i discord.js@12.5.3
```

The latest discord.js version doesn't function very well, so I use v12. It isn't a complicated script.

Answer (score 2):

Add Intents.

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });
```

You can also use the template available in the discord.js documentation.
[Documentation](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/#creating-the-main-file)

Answer (score 0):

```
client = new Discord.Client({intents: 32767})
```

Comment: Where should that be applied? Replacing the second code line? Or something else? Can you [extend your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71437069/edit), please? But ********************** ***without*** ********************** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.