# How do I fix CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS error (Discord.js)

Tags: discord.js

I have been trying this for 1 day now and cannot figured this error out.

**Error**

```
TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
```

**Code**

```
const { Client, Collection } = require("discord.js");
const { config } = require("dotenv");
const fs = require("fs");
const { Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({
    disableEveryone: true,
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_BANS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_EMOJIS_AND_STICKERS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_INTEGRATIONS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_WEBHOOKS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_INVITES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_TYPING, Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS, Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING],
});
```

**Node Version:** 16.6.1
**Discord Version:** "^13.0.1"
**And yes I have enable all intents from discord.com/developers**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i fix CLIENT\_MISSING\_INTENTS error - Disord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68694195/how-do-i-fix-client-missing-intents-error-disord-js)

Answer (score 0):

`clientOptions.disableMentions` has been removed and replaced with [`clientOptions.allowedMentions`](https://deploy-preview-551--discordjs-guide.netlify.app/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#allowed-mentions)

It seems that this caused the issue, and this should work.

```js
const { Client, Collection, Intents } = require("discord.js")
const { config } = require("dotenv")
const fs = require("fs")


const client = new Client({
    allowedMentions: { parse: ['users', 'roles'], repliedUser: true },
    intents: [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, 
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS, 
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_BANS, 
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_EMOJIS_AND_STICKERS, 
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_INTEGRATIONS, 
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_WEBHOOKS, 
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_INVITES, 
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES, 
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES, 
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, 
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS, 
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_TYPING, 
    Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES, 
    Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
    Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING
    ]
})
```

> Note: it is not advised to use **all** intents. Use only those you really need. This speeds up connection times, and is easier on the API.

Comment: This is not working. :((( I tried everything

Comment: Removing `disableMentions` won't have any effect as it just gets ignored by Discord.js because you're sending a JSON object.