# DISCORD JS BOT - TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

**I get the error above.**

**Here's the code:**

```
// token: ---------------------------------------------------

const token = ('') // a ''-k közé kell beírni a tokent-

// ----------------------------------------------------------


// channel id-k ----------------------------

const ofo = ('779369203572015134');
const magyar = ('797181568355008573');
const matematika = ('779368815364538398');
const angol = ('780147093850554408');
const tortenelem = ('780147128671797259');
const fizika = ('784325257754181632');
const biologia = ('784325257754181632');
const foldrajz = ('797181800661254144');
const rezidencia = ('821122601283747841');
const detox = ('743212240215212064');
const testgeneral = ('876043353593118725')

// -----------------------------------------

const schedule = require('node-schedule');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const client = new Discord.Client();




client.on("ready", () => {
    const job = schedule.scheduleJob({hour: 20, minute: 10}, () => {     
        const channel = client.channels.cache.get(testgeneral);
    
        if (!channel) return console.error("ilen csatolna nincsen embe");
        channel.join().then(connection => {
            console.log("sikeres csatlakozás.");
        }).catch(e => {
            console.error(e);
        });
    });
    client.login(token); 
});
```

Here's the error code when i type ' node . ' :
*TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.*

**Anybody has ideas how can i fix this?
Thanks**

Comment: This might be helpful: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#privileged-intents

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix CLIENT\_MISSING\_INTENTS error - Disord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68694195/how-do-i-fix-client-missing-intents-error-disord-js)

Answer (score 1):

On Discord.JS v13+ you are going to need to put intents for the client.

**Example:**

```js
const discord = require('discord.js')
const Client = new discord.Client({
  intents: [ discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES ]
})
```

You can see more at the [Discord Guides](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#enabling-intents)

**All Intents that exists are:**

- Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS
- Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS
- Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_BANS
- Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_EMOJIS_AND_STICKERS
- Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_INTEGRATIONS
- Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_WEBHOOKS
- Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_INVITES
- Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES
- Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES
- Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES
- Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS
- Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_TYPING
- Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES
- Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTION
- Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING