# Why does node main.js not work when I use it in cmd?

Tags: discord.js

So I'm learning to make a Discord bot, and when I type "node main.js" or "node ." in Command Prompt, it's supposed to get the bot online, but when I tried it, it gave me this error

```
C:\Users\Aly\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:544
      throw new TypeError('CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS');
      ^

TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
    at Client._validateOptions (C:\Users\Aly\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\←[4mdiscord.js←[24m\src\client\Client.js:544:13)
    at new Client (C:\Users\Aly\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\←[4mdiscord.js←[24m\src\client\Client.js:73:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Aly\Desktop\DiscordBot\main.js:3:16)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)←[39m
←[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47←[39m {
  [←[32mSymbol(code)←[39m]: ←[32m'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS'←[39m
}
```

Its supposed to say "SpidBot is online!", and here is the code I've written, I cant seem to find out whats wrong.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('SpidBot is online!');
});

client.login('auth token');
```

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68694195/how-do-i-fix-client-missing-intents-error-disord-js answer your question?

Comment: Welcome, this seems to be another duplicate question. Try copy-pasting your error message to google before asking questions at SO...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix CLIENT\_MISSING\_INTENTS error - Disord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68694195/how-do-i-fix-client-missing-intents-error-disord-js)

Comment: @SkulaurunMrusal The link you sent was for something a bit different. What I'm trying to do is make it say "SpidBot is online!" in CMD

Comment: @atanay also a bit different from what I wanted, its supposed to say "SpidBot is online!" in CMD

Comment: @Spademin But there is nothing wrong with the code console logging a string... The error says you are missing intents in the `Client` class constructor.

Comment: Hi,  Please *Do Not* post your code as an image, post is as a text instead. [Here is why you should not post your code as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15366635)

Comment: @SkulaurunMrusal the problem is, when other people I see do it, it works fine, same exact code and same exact steps, but it doesnt work when i try it.

Comment: That is probably because they are using discord.js v12 and you have v13. The latest stable release, which **requires** you to specify intents.

Comment: Oh, now I get it, thank you!

Comment: Also be careful with your login token, you should head to the Discord Developer Portal and reset the token, because it has been leaked.

Comment: Oh, alr. Ty again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the tutorial was using an older version of node, which caused the problems

Answer (score -2):

You Should Put

```
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("ready", () =>{
     console.log(`Connected As ${client.user.tag}`)
}
)
client.login('insert token')
```

instead of your code