# Discord Bot will not login to server

Tags: json, discord, discord.js, botframework, bots

I will start this off by saying I'm a bit new to discord bot making. I'm just trying to get the bot online at this point and I keep getting the error:

> TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
>
> at Client._validateOptions (C:\Users\levan\Desktop\Discordbot\node_modules\←[4mdiscord.js←[24m\src\client\Client.js:544:13)
> at new Client (C:\Users\levan\Desktop\Discordbot\node_modules\←[4mdiscord.js←[24m\src\client\Client.js:73:10)
> at Object. (C:\Users\levan\Desktop\Discordbot\main.js:3:16) ←[90m
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)←[39m

```
←[90m
```

> at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)←[39m

```
←[90m
```

> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)←[39m

```
`←[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)←[39`m
```

``` ←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] ``(node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)←[39m ```

```
←[90m    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47←[39m {

  [←[32mSymbol(code)←[39m]: ←[32m'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS'←[39m

}
```

thus far this is what I have

---

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();



client.once('ready', () => {
console.log('Tec Control Bot is online!');
});



client.login('redacted sign in key');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix CLIENT\_MISSING\_INTENTS error - Disord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68694195/how-do-i-fix-client-missing-intents-error-disord-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you are using discord.js v13 which is a lot different from the previous version which is v12. In v13, it is compulsory to add intents.

You can read this for more information: [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#enabling-intents)

Answer (score 0):

new Discord version V13 requires you to set the intents your bot will use.

First, you can go to https://ziad87.net/intents/ where you can choose the intents you want and gives you a number, you should use that number like this:

```
const intents = new Discord.Intents(INTENTS NUMBER);
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents });
```

For example, if you want all the intents, you will have:

```
const intents = new Discord.Intents(32767);
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents });
```