# Client Missing Intents

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have decided I wanted to make my own Discord bot so I started watching a tutorial on Youtube by @CodeLyon. I have followed the procedures exactly and this is my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Vibre is online!');
});
```

Of course, I have not included the Client Login code but when I try to "run" this program in command prompt with "node .", this is what happens:

```
    C:\Users\Isaac\Desktop\DiscordBot>node .
    C:\Users\Isaac\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:544
      throw new TypeError('CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS');
      ^

    TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
        at Client._validateOptions 
  (C:\Users\Isaac\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\←[4mdiscord.js←[24m\src\client\Client.js:544:13)
        at new Client 
    
   (C:\Users\Isaac\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\←[4mdiscord.js←[24m\src\client\Client.js:73:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Isaac\Desktop\DiscordBot\main.js:3:16)
    ←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)←[39m
    ←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)←[39m
    ←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)←[39m
    ←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)←[39m
    ←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] 
    (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)←[39m
    ←[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47←[39m {
      [←[32mSymbol(code)←[39m]: ←[32m'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS'←[39m
    }
```

Can somebody please help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix CLIENT\_MISSING\_INTENTS error - Disord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68694195/how-do-i-fix-client-missing-intents-error-disord-js)

Answer (score 0):

In CodeLyon's video he used discord.js@12.2.0 but now discord.js updated to 13.1.0 and with this updated you must send ClientOptions as a parameter while creating new client. So now you need to specify the events which you want your bot to receive using gateway intents.

Instead of

```
const client = new Discord.Client();
```

Use

```
const client = new Discord.Client({intents: [Enter intents you need here]});
```

Example

```
const client = new Discord.Client({intents: ["GUILD", "GUILD_MESSAGES"]})
```