# Discord Bot With Node.js CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So, I'm new at programming JS Discord Bots, but have a few years experience with C#, Java and some other languages. But I'm following this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BmKXBVdEV0g), but already at 13:15 I'm off. A ton of things is showing op in PowerShell, and I don't understand. Here you got it:

```
require("dotenv").config();

const { Client } = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Client();

bot.login(process.env.DISCORDJS_BOT_TOKEN);
```

And I get these errors:

```
C:\Users\CENSORED\OneDrive\Dokumenter\discord-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:544
      throw new TypeError('CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS');
      ^

TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
    at Client._validateOptions (C:\Users\CENSORED\OneDrive\Documents\discord-bot\node_modules\←[4mdiscord.js←[24m\src\client\Client.js:544:13)
    at new Client (C:\Users\CENSORED\OneDrive\Documents\discord-bot\node_modules\←[4mdiscord.js←[24m\src\client\Client.js:73:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\CENSORED\OneDrive\Documents\discord-bot\src\bot.js:4:13)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)←[39m
←[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47←[39m {
  [←[32mSymbol(code)←[39m]: ←[32m'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS'←[39m
}
```

So, right here, I'm 100% clueless. I'd be more than happy to get some help! If you do, I don't know how to explain how much I love it.

Comment: Duplicate: [How do I fix CLIENT\_MISSING\_INTENTS error - Disord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68694195/how-do-i-fix-client-missing-intents-error-disord-js) (please google error messages before posting here)

Comment: Also this tutorial is outdated. There has been a new major release of Discord.js with multiple breaking changes