# Discord.js 'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS' Error

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I am trying to make my Discord bot appear online, but I am getting an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fBxk.png)

Code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready' , () => {
    console.log('Bot is online');
});

client.login('My token');
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix CLIENT\_MISSING\_INTENTS error - Disord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68694195/how-do-i-fix-client-missing-intents-error-disord-js)

Answer (score 1):

`Intents` were introduced in `discord.js v13` and ensure that the bot only does what it intends to do - i.e. it doesn't waste processing power.

```js
//example from the official Discord.js guide
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const myIntents = new Intents();
myIntents.add(Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS);

const client = new Client({ intents: myIntents });

client.login('mytoken');
```

[The docs](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#enabling-intents) are always a good place to look first.