# How to fix 'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS' error in discord.js?

Tags: discord, discord.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();



client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Meep is online!');
});




client.login('my token was here');
```

When I run code, I get 'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS' error, how to fix it?

I was not getting this error in older discord.js versions, I started getting this error when I updated to the new discord.js version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix CLIENT\_MISSING\_INTENTS error - Disord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68694195/how-do-i-fix-client-missing-intents-error-disord-js)

Comment: yes ıt's worked

Answer (score 0):

You can use any intents you want
with this intents you just can see guilds and messages in guilds

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client({intents : [
    Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES
]})



client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Meep is online!');
});




client.login('my token was here');
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most straight forward way in my opinion is using

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({
  intents: [Object.keys(GatewayIntentBits)],
  partials: [Object.keys(Partials)],
});
```

The `Object.keys(GatewayIntentBits)` expression is used to retrieve all the keys (names) of the GatewayIntentBits and same for `Object.keys(Partials)` object and create an array with those names. It might take up more resources but is the best workaround if you do not have limited resources.
If you are interested, learn more about Javascript Object here [Object - Javascript| MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

Answer (score -4):

```js
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_BANS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_EMOJIS_AND_STICKERS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_INTEGRATIONS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_WEBHOOKS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_INVITES,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_TYPING,
        Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES,
        Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
        Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING
    ]
});
```

Comment: This is bad code. This adds every intent possible instead of just specific ones. An explanation would also be beneficial.

Comment: Only intents that are actually needed should be used

Comment: Only use intents you actually gonna use. Don't include them all if you're not gonna use them.