# This error is occurring when I'm going to create a bot in js and I can't fix it. Can someone help me?

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

I need help creating a discord bot in js. Before we could do it without 'intents', but now discord practically obliges and I'm new to programming so I have no idea how to put these 'intents'! if anyone knows and can help me I'm immensely grateful, here below is an example of the error and how is my code! Thanks.

The error:

```
TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
    at Client._validateOptions (C:\Users\arthu\3D Objects\BotBuscape\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:544:13)
    at new Client (C:\Users\arthu\3D Objects\BotBuscape\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:73:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\arthu\3D Objects\BotBuscape\index.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS'
}
```

My code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js'); 
const Client = new Discord.Client();
const config = require("./config.json")

bot.login(); 

bot.once('ready', () => { console.log(`Bot online: ${bot.user.tag}!`); }); 
bot.on("guildMemberAdd", member => { member.send(`Seja bem vindo! Siga as regras do servidor e divirta-se ðŸ˜€`) });

client.login('config.token')
```

Comment: please check in the sdk (https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-handling.html#individual-command-files)
 
```const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });```

Answer (score 0):

**This seems like a duplicate of [How do I fix CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS error - Disord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68694195/how-do-i-fix-client-missing-intents-error-disord-js)
.**

In short, since v8 you have to specify which events you need to receive in your bot.

**Example**

```
const Client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [your intents] });
```

You can see a full list [**here**](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#gateway-intents).
And then you can use it as:

```
const Client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILD_CREATE", "GUILD_UPDATE"] });
```