# Discord JavaScript Error Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot from a [tutorial](https://ujeb.se/3osBn8) on yt. I'm a beginner in JS programming.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {

console.log('Bot is online!');

});

client.login('My token');
```

and when i write in cmd "node ." i got this error

> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\48795\Desktop\DiscordBot\main.js'.
> Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
>
> ←[90m at tryPackage (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:320:19)←[39m
>
> ←[90m at Function.Module._findPath
> (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:533:18)←[39m
>
> ←[90m at resolveMainPath (internal/modules/run_main.js:16:25)←[39m
>
> ←[90m at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain]
> (internal/modules/run_main.js:70:24)←[39m
>
> ←[90m at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47←[39m {
>
> code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
>
> path: ←[32m'C:\Users\48795\Desktop\DiscordBot\package.json'←[39m,
>
> requestPath: ←[32m'C:\Users\48795\Desktop\DiscordBot'←[39m
>
> }

How do i fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

In your package.json, you need to put in the main field, the name of your script. In your case whatever you named your file.

Comment: My main file is "main.js"

Answer (score 0):

The error tells me at least that your index/main file is different in your `package.json` than it really is. What is your main file called?

You should try renaming it to `main.js` OR just rename the main field in your `package.json` file.

Comment: My main file called "mine.js". This is my package script `{
  "name": "discordbot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^13.1.0"
  }
}
`

Comment: Rename it to `main.js`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, my main file is called main.js

Comment: Move the `main.js` file out of the node_modules directory. You should have folder `bot` or anything else you wanna call it then inside `bot` your `package.json` files and `node_modules` folder snd `main.js`

Comment: I move the main.js to my project folder and I get this error       C:\Users\48795\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:544
      throw new TypeError('CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS');
      ^

TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
    at Client._validateOptions (C:\Users\48795\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\←[4mdiscord.js←[24m\src\client\Client.js:544:13)

Comment: my project folder is DiscordBot

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68694195/how-do-i-fix-client-missing-intents-error-disord-js

Answer (score 0):

In your package.json you need to make sure your "main" field points to your main.js file. Its probably looking for index.js.

Comment: My main file is "main.js"

Comment: is your main.js inside of a folder such as src? if so you need to put src/main.js as the value.

Comment: I'm don't know what is src. main.js is in folder DiscordBot>node_modules.

Comment: where is your main.js file located? is it in the root of the project folder or is it nested inside a folder?

Comment: My project folder is "DiscordBot" and main.js is in DiscordBot/node_modules

Comment: That's not your main.js. That's the main.js for a node_modules. What is the name of the file that you typed the code above in? When you call the node command you need to pass in the file that your main program uses to start up.
`node <filename>`