# Discord bot, Missing intent

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I found a discord bot source on github, i try to start it but i got an error. Anyone can help please?

Code:
[Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSTAS.png)

Error:

TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
at Client._validateOptions (C:\Users\Krisz\Desktop\CalypsoBot-develop\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:544:13)
at new Client (C:\Users\Krisz\Desktop\CalypsoBot-develop\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:73:10)
at new Client (C:\Users\Krisz\Desktop\CalypsoBot-develop\src\Client.js:20:5)
at Object. (C:\Users\Krisz\Desktop\CalypsoBot-develop\app.js:17:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
[Symbol(code)]: 'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS'
}

Comment: Googling "client missing intents" will give many results of the same question here on this site. Research first before posting

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix CLIENT\_MISSING\_INTENTS error - Disord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68694195/how-do-i-fix-client-missing-intents-error-disord-js)