# An issue in making my bot online in discord

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, discord

(Node version: 14.17.6)

When I type `node .`  in terminal, it gives me this issue:

> throw new TypeError('CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS');
> ^

> TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
> at Client._validateOptions (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:544:13)
> at new Client (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:73:10)
> at Object. (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Discord Bot\index.js:2:13)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
> at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
> [Symbol(code)]: 'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS'
> }

what I wrote in VSC:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const token ='MY TOKEN';

bot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('This bot is online!');
})

bot.on("message", msg=>{
    if (msg.content === "HELLO"){
        msg.reply('HELLO FRIEND!');
    }
})   
    
bot.login(token);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix CLIENT\_MISSING\_INTENTS error - Disord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68694195/how-do-i-fix-client-missing-intents-error-disord-js)

Comment: I already fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client doesn't have intents
These would be your main ones

```
let bot = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] })
```

Comment: for more help here's the [discord.js guide site](https://discordjs.guide/#before-you-begin)

Comment: So I switched `const bot = new Discord.Client();` to `let bot = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] })`

Comment: But it's still giveng me the same error

Comment: I just downloaded node the last version and it works!..Thanks