# Discord bot client missing intents error while trying to run bot

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to configure a discord bot and I'm in my final steps and I keep getting this error message.

Everything was going so smoothly and I was following steps and suddenly

```
/Users/mista/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:544
      throw new TypeError('CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS');
      ^

TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
    at Client._validateOptions (/Users/mista/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:544:13)
    at new Client (/Users/mista/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:73:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mista/Downloads/SMSBotBypass/bots/discord/bot.js:5:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS'
}
```

That's the bot I'm trying to configure `https://github.com/Ross1337/SMSBotBypass`

Comment: Hi there, it seems as though you may be using a deprecated way of intents. A question here has an answer that you may try:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68694258/12819985

Comment: Also you may need to update your version of node as mentioned in the comments of the answer I sent. `npm install node@16` in shell.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix CLIENT\_MISSING\_INTENTS error - Disord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68694195/how-do-i-fix-client-missing-intents-error-disord-js)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you didn't put any Intents or put an invalid Intents on the Client. There is an official [discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide) that is really helpful.

To add Intents to your client:

```js
// Extracting Intents from DJS V13
const { Intents, Client } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
       Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
       Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    ]
});
```

The Intents I put is just basic Intents for a bot. To see what intents you really need, and what intents give you there is the official documentation of [Discord Intents](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#list-of-intents)