# Uncaught TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js, client

hey i've tried almost every tutorial in here but it still shows me uncaught typerror.. it keeps doing it even after i've seen and did what the others too had (i mean the same problem) but it just won't work
every thing hasn't worked i don't know what to do
i've also tried to put the intent thing but it says that the const client = new Discord.Client(); needs to be changed or idk what to do anymore any help would be really great for me.
my main script is this:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');



if(!fs.existsSync('./data/servers.json')) {
    console.log('servers.json does not exist');
    console.log('Creating servers.json...');
    fs.writeFileSync('./data/servers.json', '{}', err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
    console.log('Success!');
}
if(!fs.existsSync('./data/config.json')) {
    console.log('config.json does not exist');
    console.log('Creating config.json...');
    fs.writeFileSync('./data/config.json', '{"defaultPrefix": "!"}', err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
    console.log('Success!');
}
if(!process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN) {
    console.log('The DISCORD_TOKEN environment variable is not defined');
    if(!fs.existsSync('./.env')) {
        console.log('.env does not exist');
        console.log('Creating .env...');
        fs.writeFileSync('./.env', 'DISCORD_TOKEN=', err => {
            console.error(err);
        });
        console.log('Success!');
    }
    console.log('Please, set the DISCORD_TOKEN environment variable or add it in .env');
}

const servers = require('../exports/exports.js');
const defaultPrefix = require('../data/config.json').defaultPrefix;

const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for(const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require('./commands/' + file);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}


client.once('ready', () => {
    client.user.setStatus('online');
    client.user.setActivity(defaultPrefix + 'help', {  type: 'LISTENING'  });
    console.log('Ready!');
});


client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    let prefix = servers.getPrefix(message.guild.id);
    if(message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix)) {
        const args = message.content.toLowerCase().slice(prefix.length).split(' ');
        if(!client.commands.has(args[0])) return;
        try {
            client.commands.get(args[0]).execute(message, args.slice(1, args.length), prefix);
        }
        catch(err) {
            console.error(err);
            message.reply('Something went wrong while executing that command');
        }
    }
    else if(message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(defaultPrefix + 'help')) {
        const args = message.content.toLowerCase().slice(prefix.length).split(' ');
        try {
            client.commands.get('help').execute(message, args.slice(1, args.length), prefix);
        }
        catch(err) {
            message.reply('Something went wrong while executing that command');
        }
    }
});

async function close() {
    console.log('Received terminate signal');
    console.log('Closing');
    process.exit();
}

process.on('SIGINT', close);
process.on('SIGTERM', close);
client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);
```

Comment: You are looking at years-old tutorials, designed for discord.js v11. The latest version is discord.js v13, and things have changed. You need to provide "intents" when constructing your client. Check out the [official guide](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/#creating-the-main-file), and take a look at the list of intents on the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Intents?scrollTo=s-FLAGS).

Comment: This question is also a duplicate of the following one, and could answer your question: [How do I fix CLIENT\_MISSING\_INTENTS error - Disord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68694195/how-do-i-fix-client-missing-intents-error-disord-js)

Answer (score 0):

Really easy solution is:

```js
const client = new Client({
    intents: 32767
});
```

But you also need to have all intents enabled in your bot settings at https://discord.com/developers