# throw new TypeError('CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS');

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I was making my discord bot, and this error accrued:

```
C:\Users\spoti\Desktop\SGHbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:544
      throw new TypeError('CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS');
      ^

TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
    at Client._validateOptions (C:\Users\spoti\Desktop\SGHbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:544:13)
    at new Client (C:\Users\spoti\Desktop\SGHbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:73:10)    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\spoti\Desktop\SGHbot\bot.js:2:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS'
}
```

here is my bot.js :

```
const Discord = require('discord.js'); 
const robot = new Discord.Client(); 
const comms = require("./comms.js"); 
const fs = require('fs'); 
let config = require('./config.json'); 
let token = config.token;
let prefix = config.prefix; 

robot.on("ready", function() {
  console.log(robot.user.username + " запустился!");
});


robot.on('message', (msg) => { 
  if (msg.author.username != robot.user.username && msg.author.discriminator != robot.user.discriminator) {
    var comm = msg.content.trim() + " ";
    var comm_name = comm.slice(0, comm.indexOf(" "));
    var messArr = comm.split(" ");
    for (comm_count in comms.comms) {
      var comm2 = prefix + comms.comms[comm_count].name;
      if (comm2 == comm_name) {
        comms.comms[comm_count].out(robot, msg, messArr);
      }
    }
  }
});


robot.login(token);
```

comms.js :

```
const config = require('./config.json');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const prefix = config.prefix;
const versions = config.versions;


// Команды //

function test(robot, mess, args) {
  mess.channel.send("Я - сан ген бот! И я точно не умру в 3 серии игры в к")
}

function hello(robot, mess, args) {
  mess.reply("Здравствуйте")
}


// Список комманд //

var comms_list = [{
    name: "test",
    out: test,
    about: "Тестовая команда"
  },
  {
    name: "hello",
    out: hello,
    about: "Команда для приветствия!"
  }
}

module.exports.comms = comms_list;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix CLIENT\_MISSING\_INTENTS error - Disord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68694195/how-do-i-fix-client-missing-intents-error-disord-js)

Answer (score 1):

You must enter the intents at line 2,
Example

```js
const robot = new Discord.Client(
{
   "INTENTS": [Intents here]
}
);
```