# I keep getting this error [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provide

Tags: discord, discord.js

I keep getting this error

```
C:\WINDOWS\Temp\OneDrive\Documents\microsoft\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:544
      throw new TypeError('CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS');
      ^
TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client
```

but when I do add it it says client is declared

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')

const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("Bot is online!")
}); 

const allIntents = new Intents(32767);
```

how do I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix CLIENT\_MISSING\_INTENTS error - Disord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68694195/how-do-i-fix-client-missing-intents-error-disord-js)

Answer (score 3):

Since discord.js v13, you're required to explicitly pass intents when instantiating a new Client.

**Intents** are what tells Discord about which events your bot wants to receive, so it doesn't send too much unnecessary stuff that you're not going to use in your code.

To do this, you don't even have to do the numbers thing. The library supports passing intents as an array of strings (and then it does the math behind the scenes).

Here's an example if you wanted to receive some information about the guilds your bot is in:

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [
        'GUILDS',
        'GUILD_MEMBERS'
    ]
});
```

You can add as many intents as you want, and a complete list of the currently supported ones can be found [in this discord.js documentation page](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Intents?scrollTo=s-FLAGS). There's also [this official documentation page by Discord](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#list-of-intents) that tells you which intent controls which events.

Comment: Just as an addition: it's better to use parameters from `Discord.Intents` object instead of strings. Something like `Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS` and `Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS`. Like in [this example](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) on Discord.JS documentation site.

Comment: They are both valid. They don't need to change it.