# TypeError [ClientMissingIntents]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client

Tags: discord.js

I am having following error in the code while creating bot in discord.js on replit

> TypeError [ClientMissingIntents]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
> at Client._validateOptions (/home/runner/EncourageBotjs/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:479:13)
> at new Client (/home/runner/EncourageBotjs/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:78:10)
> at Object. (/home/runner/EncourageBotjs/index.js:2:16)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)

following is code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('Logged in!');
});

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'ping') {
    msg.reply('Pong!');
  }
});

const mySecret = process.env['TOKEN']
client.login(mySecret);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I keep getting this error \[CLIENT\_MISSING\_INTENTS\]: Valid intents must be provide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69658753/i-keep-getting-this-error-client-missing-intents-valid-intents-must-be-provid)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `Intents` to work your bot.

If you're using `discordjs v14` Here's how you use `Intents`:

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages
  ]
});
```

Since v14 added `GateWayIntentBits` instead of `Intents`. And here's how you use `Intents` on v13:

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js')
const client = new Client({intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES ] })
```

Since `GateWayIntentBits` is not added on v13 discord. You can look at your `package.json` to see what version you're using under `dependencies`

```js
"dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^13.6.0", //This will be your version
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "mongoose": "^6.4.0",
    "ms": "^2.1.3",
    "node.js": "^0.0.1-security"
  }
```