# Valid intents must be provided for the Client

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm programming a discord bot and I can't get rid of this error. I have already seen a couple of solutions that worked for others but it's not working for me... I keep getting this error:

> ```
> throw new TypeError('CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS');
>   ^ TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
> at Client._validateOptions (C:\Users\User\Desktop\discordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:548:13)
> at new Client (C:\Users\User\Desktop\discordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:76:10)
> at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\discordBot\main.js:3:16)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
> at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {   [Symbol(code)]: 'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS' }
> ```

this is my main.js code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
 
const client = new Discord.Client({ partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION" ]});
 
const prefix = '-';
 
const fs = require('fs');
 
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
 
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
 
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
 
 
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('bot is online!');
});
 
 
client.on('message', message => {
 
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
 
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    if (command === 'reactionrole') {
        client.commands.get('reactionrole').execute(message, args, Discord, client);
    } 
  
});
 
client.login('TOKEN');
```

does anyone know what I can do about this?

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory, your `client` is missing `intents`. https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ClientOptions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix CLIENT\_MISSING\_INTENTS error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68694195/how-do-i-fix-client-missing-intents-error)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the intents field when making a new client. Replace

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({ partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION" ]});
```

with

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({ partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION" ], intents: ["GUILDS", /* Other intents... */]});
```