# How do I fix CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS error when creating a Discord Price Bot?

Tags: node.js, discord.js, bots, price

Am new to programming with JS and am trying to make a crypto price bot for my Discord server. I have copied the code from another user and download all the needed packages. I am now getting this error every time I try and actually Node the project:

TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
at Client._validateOptions (/Users/oliver/Desktop/Discord/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:548:13)
at new Client (/Users/oliver/Desktop/Discord/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:76:10)
at Object. (/Users/oliver/Desktop/Discord/PriceBot.js:3:16)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
[Symbol(code)]: 'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS'
}

Here is the code I am using. Any specific changes would be greatly appreciated as I am new to this:

```
const axios = require('axios')
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()
// variables
const coinId = 'ethereum'; // https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/list
const guildId = 'Server_ID'; // Right click server icon on discord -> copy 
id
// const clientId = ''; // get it from your dev portal 
https://discord.com/developers/applications
const botSecret = 'Bot_ID'; // 
get it from your dev portal https://discord.com/developers/applications
// Invite bot to server:
// https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize? 
client_id=APP_ID&permissions=0&scope=bot%20applications.commands
function getPrices() {
// API for price data.
axios.get(`https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets? 
vs_currency=usd&ids=${coinId}`).then(res => {
// If we got a valid response
if(res.data && res.data[0].current_price && res.data[0].price_change_percentage_24h) 
{
let currentPrice = res.data[0].current_price || 0 // Default to zero
let priceChangePct = res.data[0].price_change_percentage_24h || 0 // Default to zero
let priceChange = res.data[0].price_change_24h || 0 // Default to zero
let symbol = res.data[0].symbol.toUpperCase() || '?'
client.user.setPresence({
game: {
// Example: "Watching -5,52% | BTC"
name: `${priceChange.toFixed(2)} (${priceChangePct.toFixed(2)}%)`,
type: 3 // Use activity type 3 which is "Watching"
}
})
console.log('Updated price to', currentPrice)
client.guilds.find(guild => guild.id === `${guildId}`).me.setNickname(`${symbol} 
$${(currentPrice).toLocaleString().replace(/,/g,',')}`)
}
else
console.log('Could not load player count data for', process.env.COIN_ID)
}).catch(err => console.log('Error at api.coingecko.com data:', err))
}
// Runs when client connects to Discord.
client.on('ready', () => {
console.log('Logged in as', client.user.tag)
getPrices() // Ping server once on startup
// Ping the server and set the new status message every x minutes. (Minimum of 1 
minute)
setInterval(getPrices, Math.max(1, 1 || 1) * 60 * 1000)
})
```

Comment: Hey, your bot secret token should be secret! I highly recommend you regenerate it on discord dashboard.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix CLIENT\_MISSING\_INTENTS error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68694195/how-do-i-fix-client-missing-intents-error)

Answer (score -3):

thats a simple fix!

In v13 of discord, we are required to specify intents for our bots in order for them to work properly.. You can use the below code, and hope this fixes your issue!

```
const { Client, Discord, Intents } = require('discord.js')
client = new Client({ intents: 32767 });
```

also make sure to regenerate your bots secret token, since you have it displayed (Thats to ensure others can steal it and use it).

I recommend that you make a config folder of some kind, and keep your private info in there like your bots token.

Comment: Does this replace the code that already there? (const Discord = require('discord.js') --->  const { Discord, Intents } = require('discord.js')
client = new Client({ intents: 32767 });. As it now spits out a different error saying "Client in not defined"

Comment: Yes replace that with what you have.. Ill edit my message for the error that you have now

Comment: Why would you specify all intents when all of them aren't necessary.

Comment: Its an example, they can change them by specifying the intents they need like `"GUILD_PRESENCES", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "GUILD_BANS"` and so on...