# Node saying sh: 1: main.js: not found when main.js is there

Tags: node.js, npm, discord.js

As the title says, node cannot find main.js. I am doing this through replit and my .replit file is `run = "npm test"`. My package.json file is

```
{
  "name": "Adventure",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This is The Adventure Bot By BrainDead_Dev",
  "main": "main.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@replit/database": "^2.0.1",
    "discord-buttons": "^4.0.0-deprecated",
    "discord.js": "^13.6.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "winston": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "main.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/BrainDeadDev/Adventure.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/BrainDeadDev/Adventure/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/BrainDeadDev/Adventure#readme"
}
```

This is for a discord bot, and it has been working perfectly fine up until the point where I wanted to update discord.js and had to reinstall npm. Any help would be appreciated as I am quite lost.

Comment: change `main.js` to `node main.js`

Comment: It now tells me `Error: Cannot find module 'node:events'` which is the error I had earlier...

Comment: what do you get when you type `node --version` in the terminal? You will need at least v16.6

Comment: I get v12.22.6.

Comment: you need to update node then

Comment: I've been trying to for a while, but no matter what I do, replit wont let me update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you updated the discord.js package, it now requires a more current version of node js (v16.6).

To update to the version of node using npm simply run:

```
npm install -g n
```

If you are using nvm you can do:

```
nvm install 16.6
```

then tell nvm to use the new version:

```
nvm use 16.6
```

Then you can check the version you are using by running:

```
node --version
```

Edit for Repl.it:

following [this blog](https://dev.to/arnavkr/updating-node-js-to-16-in-replit-1ep0), you should be able to do it by running this:

```
npm i --save-dev node@16 && npm config set prefix=$(pwd)/node_modules/node && export PATH=$(pwd)/node_modules/node/bin:$PATH
```

You can also try following this question on [repl.it forums](https://replit.com/talk/ask/How-Can-I-Update-NodeJS-Version/42698)

Comment: When I tried the first, I got the error of ```npm ERR! code EROFS
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging
npm ERR! errno -30
npm ERR! rofs EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging'
npm ERR! rofs Often virtualized file systems, or other file systems
npm ERR! rofs that don't support symlinks, give this error.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2022-02-13T19_56_32_493Z-debug.log```. I am not using nvm.

Comment: I have updated the answer for repl.it. try those

Comment: That worked, thank you! Edit: Nevermind, I got a new error when trying to start. `throw new TypeError('CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS');`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68694258/9583747

Comment: Never mind, all good. I got it to work.