# Why do I keep getting this error when I try to get my discord bot online

Tags: discord.js

I tried making a discord bot and I did the first steps and the command prompt when I type node . shows this:

TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
at Client._validateOptions (C:\Users\giann\Desktop\BWKS\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:548:13)
at new Client (C:\Users\giann\Desktop\BWKS\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:76:10)
at Object. (C:\Users\giann\Desktop\BWKS\main.js:2:16)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
[Symbol(code)]: 'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS'
}

I tried almomst everything but this error is coming up all the time.

the code:

```
const client = new Discord.Client();



client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready')
});

client.login('the token');
```

Comment: I fixed the issue by downloading the v12 of discord.js. npm i discord.js@12.5.3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix CLIENT\_MISSING\_INTENTS error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68694195/how-do-i-fix-client-missing-intents-error)

Answer (score 0):

Discord needs to know what intents you want to use. So to fix your code, use:

```
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [<ARRAY WITH ALL INTENTS>] });



client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready')
});

client.login('the token');
```

You can add intents in the array by using a string `"GUILDS"` or use the property `Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS`

A list of all intents can be found here: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Intents