# Having problems fixing Discord.js error TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So, I just started coding a bot in Javascript, something I have never worked with before. I am following the exact steps I see in the video, although, when I run `node .` in the terminal, I get an error:

```
TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
    at Client._validateOptions (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\Discord\Bots\SE\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:548:13)
    at new Client (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\Discord\Bots\SE\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:76:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\Discord\Bots\SE\index.js:2:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS'
}
```

This is my code:

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, 
Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const token = 'i aint showing you my token';
const PREFIX = '';

bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('SEBot is online.')

})
bot.login(token)
```

I don't understand what the problem is, and some help would really work out. Thanks.

Comment: This problem has been posted alot on this site: [How do I fix CLIENT\_MISSING\_INTENTS error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68694195/how-do-i-fix-client-missing-intents-error)

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, you already initialized your client with

```
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, 
Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
```

Then you initialized another one, which is useless now. You should remove

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
```

also your client (which has valid intents) should be the one that you call the `.on()` function, so switch `bot.on()` and `bot.login()` to `client.on` and `client.login`

Comment: And that came that amazing feeling when something is fixed. Thank you so much.